# List of customers having a specific product in their wishlist (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce with a wishlist plugin. I'd like to get a list of customers having a specific product in their wishlist. My goal is to send an out-of-stock email to every customer that has a product going out-of-stock in their own wishlist.

Is there an efficient way to do that ?

Comment: Name of this wishlist plugin ? The basic is you get all customers then loop customers with wishlist then get the product ids then for each product check if quantity is under some amount then use wp_mail for example to send email.

Comment: I'm usine Yith Wishlist (did not know if we could name the plugins here). I was looking for a way where I could avoid going through all the customers but I guess I have no choice !

Comment: I am asking this because in premium you have access to more functions - https://yithemes.com/themes/plugins/yith-woocommerce-wishlist/ also the team will help you get this list. Or you can check this table in your database - yith_wcwl where you can get product id and return user ids. See my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Like i said YITH wishlist is adding 2 tables in your database. From there you can pull the required information.

```
function 53298wcwl_get_users_by_product_id() {
    global $wpdb;
    //Change product id 24 to what you looking for
    $user_ids = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}yith_wcwl WHERE prod_id = 24"); 

    if($user_ids):
        error_log('This product was found in following wishlists for users:');
        foreach($user_ids as $id):
            $user_id = $id->user_id;
            //Access to user data from where you can pull w/e user data you want like email F name L name etc.
            $user_data = get_userdata($user_id);
            $email = $user_data->user_email;
            $fname = $user_data->first_name;
            $lname = $user_data->last_name;

            //Enable debug to see the list in debug.log
            error_log($fname.' '.$lname.' - '.$email );

        endforeach;
    endif;
}
add_action('admin_init','53298wcwl_get_users_by_product_id');
```